# Unable to update hostname output for Ubuntu Server (on Digital Ocean)

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I recently created a droplet server at Digital Ocean named:

```
ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01-2016-03-13
```

and then did a rename on the server at the Digital Ocean control panel, to `exchange.mydomain.com`.

Furthermore, I did the following command:

```
sudo echo "exchange.mydomain.com" > /etc/hostname
```

And verified it changed by doing `nano /etc/hostname`

However, when I type in `hostname` at the command prompt, the value is not reflecting the update.  What is the problem and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distros which use `systemd` use `hostnamectl` to set their hostname:

```
$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname exchange.mydomain.com
```

You'll have to log off and back in again to see the change in your shell prompt, but the `hostname` command will show the change as soon as you've ran the command.

#### Usage

```
$ sudo hostnamectl --help
hostnamectl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND ...

Query or change system hostname.

  -h --help              Show this help
     --version           Show package version
     --no-ask-password   Do not prompt for password
  -H --host=[USER@]HOST  Operate on remote host
  -M --machine=CONTAINER Operate on local container
     --transient         Only set transient hostname
     --static            Only set static hostname
     --pretty            Only set pretty hostname

Commands:
  status                 Show current hostname settings
  set-hostname NAME      Set system hostname
  set-icon-name NAME     Set icon name for host
  set-chassis NAME       Set chassis type for host
  set-deployment NAME    Set deployment environment for host
  set-location NAME      Set location for host
```